# Set all TextBox to null when the page is refreshed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an asp.net web application. i want all my textboxes to set to null when i reload the page
i am using this code but its not working

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    TextBox1.Focus();
    TextBox1.Text = null;
}
```

I also tried

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    TextBox1.Focus();
    TextBox1.Text = "";
}
```

`TextBox1` stays focused as the page is refreshed but the text does not set to null. what is the problem with my code?

Comment: Try setting `TextBox1.Focus()` *after* you set `TextBox1.Text` to null.

Comment: pls makesure if it's attributes are not set ready only.

Comment: You may have set a `placeholder`on textbox ?

Comment: Or may be your textbox is getting value from client side code `javascript/jquery`.

Comment: Show the markup for your text controls. Also, are you sure a PostBack is _not_ occurring in your reload?

Comment: i am not using any placeholder @MairajAhmad

Comment: usng focu() after null call didnt work @diiN_

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Width="365px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: @Iqra Then what is showing in textbox ?

Comment: the value i last entered stays there when i refresh or reload the page

Comment: i want the filled fields to get empty as i reload the form

Comment: do you have any script(JavaScript code) which use or maybe fill it?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the ViewState of these textboxes?

Comment: i have not used any javascrit @vahidkargar

Comment: how can i disable the viewstate? can u please elaborate it @ShayLivyatan

Comment: press control+F5 to refresh your page, or open your page in another browser.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, and you probably handled it by yourself by now - but for the sake of future visitors to this page, read here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7.aspx